deployer not defined error in smartcontract
hello guys there is an error deployer not defined could you help me finding the error?

I have defined deployer in hardhat.config.js whose code i have pasted below and i have commented where deployer is defined
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("hardhat-deploy")


// const ETHEREUM_SEPOLIA_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_SEPOLIA_URL;
// const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports = {
    solidity: {
        compilers: [{ version: "0.8.8" }, { version: "0.8.0" }],
    },
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            url: "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/w6kKxRJ0gSxTi151G63DQFHqTWPfMuYy",
            accounts: [
                "b44ac27d694b6bc4efad9d01af0635ba81358c1fa193fde2ae28ef75914a7673",
            ],
            chainId: 11155111,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
        },
    },
    gasReporter: {
        // Uncomment and set to true to enable gas reporter
        // enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS !== undefined,
        currency: "USD",
    },
    namedAccounts: { // here is deployer defined
        deployer: {  
            default: 0,
        },
        user: {
            default: 1,
        },
    },
}


and the code for Fundme.test.js is
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")

describe("FundMe", async () => {
    let FundMe
    let signer
    let MockV3Aggregator
    const sendValue = ethers.parseEther("1")
    beforeEach(async () => {
        // don't use (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer, as a parameter to the getContractAt function, it will report an error !!!
        const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        signer = accounts[0]
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])

        // there is no getContract function in ethers, so using getContractAt
        const FundMeDeployment = await deployments.get("FundMe")
        FundMe = await ethers.getContractAt(
            FundMeDeployment.abi,
            FundMeDeployment.address,
            signer
        )
        const MockV3AggregatorDeployment = await deployments.get(
            "MockV3Aggregator"
        )
        MockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt(
            MockV3AggregatorDeployment.abi,
            MockV3AggregatorDeployment.address,
            signer
        )
    })

    describe("constructor", async () => {
        it("sets the aggregator address correctly", async () => {
            const response = await FundMe.priceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, MockV3Aggregator.target) // get address using target instead of address property
        })
    })

    describe("fund", async () => {
        it("it fails if you don't send enough ETH", async () => {
            await expect(FundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more ETH!"
            )
        })
        it("updates the amount funded data structure", async () => {
            await FundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
            const response = await FundMe.addressToAmountFunded(deployer)
            assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString())
        })
    })
})

could you help me with finding the error ?
